RDLC-The definition of this report is not valid or supported by this version of Reporting Services
I have rdlc which is built in 2008, now I want to add one new field into in. Currently I am using VS 2019. so, when I run the application, it is throwing error.
"The definition of this report is not valid or supported by this version of Reporting Services. The report definition may have been created with a later version of Reporting Services or contain content that is not well-formed or not valid based on Reporting Services schemas. Details: The report definition has an invalid target namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition' which cannot be upgraded."
Please help me to resolve this.
